# OpenGL program has exited with code 1 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded my pc to Windows 10 and installed Visual Studio 2015. I try to write a "Hello OpenGL" program in Visual Studio 2015, the project gets built successfully, but it has exited with code 1. All I get is that the created window appeared and disappeared very soon. Here goes my code:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello OpenGL");

    glutMainLoopEvent();

    return 0;
}
```

As I mentioned above, the project gets built successfully, here is the building reuslt:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloGL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  HelloGL.vcxproj -> D:\OpenGL Projects\HelloGL\Debug\HelloGL.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I press `F5` to debug the program, it discouraged me with the result:

```
The thread 0x23d4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x20b8 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x10d0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[7040] HelloGL.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Comment: put break-point and then debug

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Without a callback for window events, this program has nothing to do but exit immediately.

Comment: @AliKazmi Thanks for your reply. In fact I've tried to set breakpoint at the call `glutMainLoopEvent()`, this gave a console window and a normal window, so I guess the problem is 'gutMainLoopEvent()`.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, thanks to the guys who gave me a reply.
I've figured out what is the problem, All I need to do is to register a callback function for the window, so here comes the running code:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

// myDisplay
void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the screen
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello OpenGL");

    // Register a callback function for the window's repainting event
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: awwww god, where was this post 2 hours ago ?!?

Answer (score 3):

Call `glutMainLoop` instead of `glutMainLoopEvent`.

The later `glutMainLoopEvent` is a FreeGLUT specific function that allows to place GLUT event dispatch in a custom written loop; it therefore must be called from within a loop and determining when to exit the program is up to you.

`glutMainLoop` implements its own main loop and exits the program when the last window has been closed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @datenwolf. Actually I first use `glutMainLoop`, then I use `glutMainLoopEvent` instead, neither works.